# Google app server python install modules

Tags: python, pip

When I start google app engine with dev_appserver.py . I'm getting missing module error:

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I tried install it with:

```
pip install flask
```

And it didn't help.

Then I tried to install it in lib folder inside the application:

```
pip install flask -t lib
```

This didn't help neither.

Can you help to install it please?

Answer (score 1):

Your second command seems right:

```
pip install flask -t lib
```

You just need the `lib` directory to the `sys.path` in `appengine_config.py`

```
import sys


# Inserting instead of appending allows the use of newer versions of
# pure python packages of which GAE only allows outdated versions, e.g.
# setuptools, webob.
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')
```

Personally I use wheel to create a wheelhouse instead using:

```
pip wheel -e .  # Assuming dependencies are specified in setup.py
```

Or

```
pip wheel -r requirements.txt  # Assuming a requirements file is used
```

Then the wheels can be included using the following `appengine_config.py`:

```
import glob
import sys


# Prepend every library to sys.path.
sys.path[0:0] = glob.glob('wheelhouse/*')
```

I think the first solution may actually be better, because the second one won't work with `not-zip-safe` packages.